# Call Recorder Not Working After Oreo Update

Tags: android, kotlin, call-recording

I was working on call recording with nougat but since oréo, it's not working anymore.

I am using MediaRecorder for recording.It is working on other versions of android.

I've tried many others, but no success.

so i need to know if someone has been successful made this type of application with Oreo, if so, how to do this?

Comment: after oreo update it can not be possible to record calls

Comment: *not working* is not a good description of an issue, especially not a technical one. Please carefully review the Help section to learn how to ask proper questions (include your code and research, MVCE, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call recording is not allowed from Android 6 Marshmallow.
There was a workaround in native code around the root requirement, which worked until Android 8.1.

This was patched in Android 9 Pie, and since this version recording calls is not possible anymore. You can find a detailed explanation from the developer of ACR (the most popular call recorder for Android) [here](https://bitbucket.org/copluk/acr/issues/2418/kb-android-9-p-call-recording-issues).

For the Android 6-7-8 workaround, you can check an example implementation [here](https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib) (it basically uses native C++ code to bypass the check done in Java).

Comment: Can I use [this](https://github.com/ViktorDegtyarev/CallRecLib) code in Android 9 Pie if My Application is System App? Will it work?

Comment: I don't think it will work. Also, how do you make your app a system app? You have to need to sign the app with a special keystore which is in the hands of the manufacturer. Or are you on a custom rom?

Comment: I have just made my application as an administrator.

Comment: i'm working on this project from couple of days, it's working on android 7 and 8 but the is issue is it's target sdk version is set to 23 when i increase it's sdk version it crash. `libutlis.so` not found . how can I solved this error.

Comment: Is there any official link for blocking the call record in android oreo?